# An array is unavailable after running matlab code

Tags: matlab

When I run the below code, values of vf are printed in each iteration step. But after the code completely finished, when I type plot(vf) I get the error:

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'vf'.
```

Here is my code:

```
global Y
global vf
vf=[];
c=0;
for i=0:100:500
    c=c+1;
%%this is a function by which I read the data for Y
    readdata(i);    
    vf(cnt) = mean(mean(Y .* Y))
end
```

Could somebody please help me with solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little awkward with all the global declarations.

I suppose the solution is declaring `global vf` before using `plot(vf)`:

```
global vf
plot(vf)
```

See [global](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) documentation.

In case is't not working, it's hard telling why.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not plotting vf. I want to keep its value

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I think it is working now!